# Why does Filestream not use the directory I specify in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to upload files from a MVC .net core app into a specific directory that SQL SERVER FILETABLES uses. That directory is

```
DESKTOP-9I6BPHN\sqlexpress\FILESERVER\1993_WasteOfTime.mp3
```

from

```cs
var filePath = machineName + @"\sqlexpress\FILESERVER\" + formFile.FileName;
```

But when I have the line:

```cs
using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
```

It says:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\punko\source\repos\aspnetcore-mvc-series\Part6\FileUpload\DESKTOP-9I6BPHN\sqlexpress\FILESERVER\1993_WasteOfTime.mp3'.

Why isn't it using the specific directory I told it to?

Comment: You are providing a relative path. It gets appended to the current directory. No surprise. If `DESKTOP-9I6BPHN` is the name of a network share, the path must begin with ``\\``.

Comment: I did that but now it puts a C:\ at the beginning. I just want the beginning to be \\DESKTOP-916BPHN\etc...

Comment: Did you use ``"\\"`` or ``@"\\"``?

Comment: I added the @ and now it works thanks